# .parent().remove() issue

Tags: jquery, forms, clone

I have a jQuery-based form where you can add extra people to the application.  I'm cloning the first fieldset and adding it onto the end up to a max of 3 additional people. When you've added 1 extra person then you have the option to remove that person.

However, my remove button isn't working.  It was, earlier, until I added the extra functions to the cloning to change the ids of other elements within the fieldset.

I'm using:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
```

which was working originally but now it's not and I can't figure out why.

I've taken out the lines that stop the first 'delete this person' just to show that the first one still works but the rest don't. (I'll be positioning the first one off stage eventually when it's fixed)

Probably easier to see it so I put it up [here](http://www.firsttotheball.com/index2.html).

So essentially, any ideas why my 'delete this person' isn't working on everything but the first section?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Events are bound on page load so newly added element aren't.

Comment: This will most likely work, and if so the reason is that when you do `$.click()` you hook up the event handler to all *currently existing* elements matching the selector, while `$.live()` hooks it up to all *current or future* matching elements. If the blocks for new people are added after the code too hook up the event handler is run, they didn't exist when the handler was hooked up and thus weren't included in the selector *when things happened*.

Comment: @Tomas: Actually `.live()` doesn't hook up to any of the elements matching the selector. It gives a handler to the `window` or `document` (I don't remember which one), and uses document wide event delegation. For this reason I prefer to use `.delegate()`, which also uses delegation, but only within the container you define.

Comment: @patrick: You're right. Performance wise it is better to use delegate. Although delegate also uses live (with an extra parameter) internally.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Because they are doing the same thing, jQuery rolled all the functionality into one method. I think it would have been better if they just designated one public delegation method.

Answer (score 8):

The 'live' function call has been deprecated and no longer works. You can find instructions for how to rewrite functions using the replacement 'on()' method here and more info about the deprecation:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

To handle all current and newly created elements, you must now use:

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

jQuery runs on the document object, not the element and there is an additional parameter to specify which elements to watch and add event listeners to.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you close your expresion:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: brilliant! thank you soo much! really appreciate it! I used


 `$(".remove").live("click",function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();

   
    reset();
   
   }); `

and it worked! 

thanks again! fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for delete the parent:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".remove", function() { 
      $(this).parent().remove(); 
 });
```

or you can do this for delete all parents:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".remove", function() { 
      $(this).parents().remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements don't originally exist, which means you need to use `.live()` or `.delegate()`

For example, change:

use `$(".remove").click(...)` instead of `$(".remove").live("click", ...)` this