# Hide or delete single instance of repeated element when button is pressed

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

How can I remove/hide single 'bakant' elements when the a button with the class 'close' is clicked?  The elements are generated using the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L4f7pjau/

```
<div class="shape" id="plan4_shape">
    <span class="bakkant"><input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm"/><span class="times"> &times;</span> <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm"/></span>
    <span class="bakkant" id="bakkant"><input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm"/><span class="times"> &times;</span> <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm"/><button class="close" value="close1">&times;</button></span>
    <button name="add_row" class="addrow" id="addrow4" onClick="addrow()">Add row</button>
</div>
```

Comment: multiple elements/inputs with the same id is a bad idea. you should use multiple classes for each.

Comment: I get the feeling someone is having a laugh here. Both incomplete answers, that do not solve half your problems, have been upvoted. Gotta love this website :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer (for those with a low attention span):**

```
// Listen for bubbled click events, coming from delete buttons
$('.shape').on('click', '.close', function() {

  // Remove the row closest to the delete button pressed
  $(this).closest('.bakkant').remove();
});
```

### Now on to the full answer:

There are multiple issues with the existing code, so I would like to guide you through some suggestions and a working demo:

- Being able to delete the item you clone is the first problem. If you delete that you cannot add any more records. I suggest instead that you use a template item *that is not stored in the list*. I use a dummy `script` block, of unknown type, to hold the HTML of the template. Very easy to maintain.
- Also the delete needs to operate on dynamically added items, so needs to be a delegated event handler, connected to a non-changing ancestor element. I connect it to `.shape` as that is the common ancestor to all the records.
- You also have duplicate IDs for `plan4_width`, which you cannot have in a page. Make them a class instead.

### jQuery code (commented):

```
$(function() {
  // Your count of added IDs
  var i = 0;

  // Add button handler
  $('#addrow4').click(function() {

    // Get the template HTML and convert to an element
    var $clone = $($('#template').html());

    // Set the id of the new entry (assuming it needs an ID)
    $clone.attr('id', "bakkant" + ++i);

    // Add the new row to the start of the container
    $('.shape').prepend($clone);
  });

  // Listen for bubbled click events, coming from delete buttons
  $('.shape').on('click', '.close', function() {

    // Remove the row
    $(this).closest('.bakkant').remove();
  });

});
```

**Complete *Working* Solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/y52ttwfv/4/

### Notes:

- You also specified `width` for *both fields on each line*. Is one supposed to be `height`?

Comment: Dear anonymous downvoter: I gather you like doing this to working answers as some form of joke. Bad news, SO can track it and you will be [now have been] reported :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.  :) Regarding the width question, one is a width and the other is the height.

Comment: @ChriChri: Updated JSFiddle to include separate `height` and `width` classes on inputs. Obviously you many need to change things to suit your server requirements (naming etc). This is just meant to explain the various fixes I recommend.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to wrap both (the bakkant and the a button) in the same div, span or what you prefer.

Then you can find the parent of the a button and hide it, hidding this way the div with the button and the bakkand.

You can use .parent() to find the div ([jQuery API - parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/))

And .hide() to hide the div.

Comment: `offsetParent()` is used to find the "closest ancestor element that is positioned" (e.g. `absolute` or `relative`). That is not what they want to use here.

Comment: Yes, you are right I have confused with .parent(). Thanks.

Comment: Okay, now you need to add the delete handler requested: "How can I remove/hide single 'bakant' elements when the a button with the class 'close' is clicked? ". Note: the button is added dynamically

Comment: He is asking how to hide OR delete... I guess that this is asked because he doesn't want the element, no matter how. So the question is answered just with the hide or the remove.

Comment: They are dynamically added elements, so there is more to it than a simple hide/remove. Perhaps if you made a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/osov0tcx/ here you have. They are dynamically added, but if you do a deep clone you clone the events and handlers too.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).parent()` will identify the parent span.

If you were to further nest the button element, try `$(this).closest('.bakknat')`

Then use `.remove()` or `.hide()` depending. If you're going to submit the form and parse the inputs dynamically, you'll likely want to use remove.

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Here's another thread on it
[.parent().remove() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010260/parent-remove-issue)

Comment: Okay, now you need to add the delete handler requested: "How can I remove/hide single 'bakant' elements when the a button with the class 'close' is clicked? ". Note: the button is added dynamically

Comment: I assumed that this was the basis of the question based on the fiddle and his other knowledge but I guess you're right.

Comment: Yep, that was the only question asked (although there are at least 4 problems with the existing code that need attending too once you try to fix the first one).

Comment: As I completed the entire problem already, do me a favour and at least put your answer in a JSFiddle. Then you will see what you are still missing :)